# Import and Read part of PDF

Tags: c#, pdf

So I have been looking for an up to date solution on how to Read/Import a PDF in C# so that I can extract some data out of it and store it in another format.

I haven't found any answers/ressources that are recents or able to do this?

So in short I will have a PDF with lots of useless text in it, but some part of it are displayed like a table (EXCEL alike) and in those tables I need to take 1 cell of data so that I can create a LIST/Dictionnary of those values.

Sadly I can't post the data since it is confidential.

Any good library that would work in a manner similar to the XML Document of C#?

Comment: *need to take 1 cell of data* - how do you identify that cell? Do you know the exact coordinates out merely something like 3rd row, 1st column? In the first case, any decent library will do, in the latter it depends very much on the PDF in question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a resource to read data from a PDF document in C# i would use [PDFClown](http://www.csharpopensource.com/pdfclown/).

That being said, even though the data in the PDF looks "excel-like", the data and "table" structure are stored in two different, essentially unconnected parts of the PDF document in my experience. So i don't expect you to be able to find a ready-made solution to extract only the "tabular" data.

In that case, you will either have to parse out all the text and process it in some other way, or try to match up the boxes created by all the individual line segments and then extract only the text that falls within those boundaries.